# Use order by without changing the order of the groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the count of sub categories with respect to their main categories. I want to further order them by desc by each main category. Currently my code

```
select ShipperID, EmployeeID, count(*)
from orders
group by 1, 2
order by 3 desc
```

This changes the groups totally. I would be very obliged if I can get help how to order it internally by each group.

Comment: Have you tried `order by 1, 2, 3`? What's the group's sorting you're expecting for?

Comment: The group sorting I am looking for is ShipperID -> EmployeeID -> count where the max count comes first. So for every shipper it should sort with desc.

Comment: So my sugestion may fit for you. Just declare the sequence of sorting: `select ShipperID, EmployeeID, count(*) from orders  group by 1, 2 order by 1, 2, 3 desc` this will keep the Shipper and Employee together before sort descending by count

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I assume shippers and employees are somehow related to main categories and subcategories.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you simply want `ShipperId` as the first key in the `order by`:

```
select ShipperID, EmployeeID, count(*)
from orders
group by ShipperID, EmployeeID
order by ShipperID, count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to decalre the fields on `order by` clause in the same sequence you're expecting, like this:

```
select ShipperID, EmployeeID, sum(amount) 
from ORDERS 
group by 1, 2 
order by 1, 2, 3 desc
```

You can take a look into **[this working example hosted at db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b2YXYfKaXjccqBQFKTEWvy/0)**

I hope it helps.